# How to perform a case insensitive solr query with solrj

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm using Solrj as a client for Solr, in order to perform a case-insensitive query, i've declared the custom following type in my schema.xml file

```
<fieldType name="text_ci" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Then i have a field that uses this type, the match is executed against this field

```
<field name="name" type="text_ci" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

The problem is when i execute my query in Solrj's admin panel everything is fine and i got my results but from my java application (using solrj) the search seems to be case sensitive and i didn't find where i can specify and tell solrj that i want to perform a case insensitive search

As asked i've added here my solrj code

```
String[] filters = new String[1];    
filters[0] = "name:\"Obama\”";
String[] fields = new String[] { "uuid", "name" };
q = "all:*%s*";
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery(q);
query.addFilterQuery(filters);
query.setFields(fields);
query.setStart(0);  
query.setRows(5);
QueryResponse response = this.solrInstance.query(query);
SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
```

Do you have any idea guys ? Did i miss something ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show your query string ?

Comment: SolrJ is just a facade for your actions... 

How did you run the query in the admin panel? do you have a copy field declaration from the case sensitive field? What is the query you run?

Comment: its a simple query like name:"Watch" in solr admin panel if i search name:"obama" or name:"Obama" i have the same results however on Solrj the search is case sensitive, i know that Solrj is just a facade and basically call solr API but how do you explain this behaviour ? thanks

Comment: You should post your solrj code too.

Comment: Have you tried to run the same example, but with `filters[0] = "name:\"obama\”";` this time ?

Comment: Yep and i got the same behaviour too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up  creating a new type

```
  <fieldType name="ci_text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
  </fieldType>


  <field name="mysuperfield" type="ci_text" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

With this type now i can perform case-incensitive search on mysuperfield